# Creating macro for Boost path

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, boost, visual-studio-2013, macros

My team and I all use Boost with C++. We all have installed Boost at different directory paths on our respective machines. This has now become a problem because we would all like to add the project settings file (.vcxproj) to Git repo. One way to do this is to force everyone to install Boost at the same directory path and then add that path to the project properties.

But, I was wondering if there was a better way. Can I define a Boost path macro such that each user can simply define the macro as per the Boost installation path on his computer. I see such macros when I expand the macros list in *Include Additional Directories* dialog box.

How can I create such a macro in Visual STudio to assign boost path? I did not see a button to create a macro in the macros box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Custom user macros are handled using the [Property Sheets](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a4xbdz1e%28v=vs.90%29.aspx). [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5k4a0033%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) is explained how to add a new property sheet to a project. [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z1f703z5%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) is how to edit the property sheet. The property sheet edit dialog has the `Common Properties->User Macros` tab. Using it is necessary to create a new macro, for instance, `Name` is `BOOST_ROOT` and `Value` is `C:\boost_1_57_0\`.

After that the `$(BOOST_ROOT)` macro will be present in the macros list of the `Additional Include Directories` dialog. This macro is possible to user across of the project properties.

Also is possible to add this macro to the `Additional Include Directories` of the property sheet. In this case it is not necessary even to add the `$(BOOST_ROOT)` macro in the `Additional Include Directories` of the project.

Comment: There is no `User Macros` tab under `Common Properties`. I only see a References tab.

Comment: @Golazo, As far as I understood you relate to the `Common Properties` of the project, i.e. the `Project-> {Project Name} Properties`. Please open the properties of the Property Sheet and there is the `User Macros`.

Comment: When I right click the project name from Solution Explorer and go to properties, I do not see the `User Macros` tab. However if I do `View->Property Manager`, I do see the `User Macros` tab

Comment: A scenario is - 1) [to create a new property sheet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5k4a0033%28v=vs.90%29.aspx). 2) [open the property dialog of the created property sheet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z1f703z5%28v=vs.90%29.aspx). 3) create a new macro.

Comment: Why create a new property sheet? I have other settings in my current property sheets. I am worried about losing them. If I can simply add a new macro to my current property sheet, wouldn't that solve the problem?

Comment: `View->Property Manager` is exactly what you need.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73676/discussion-between-megabyte1024-and-golazo).